# Problema para executar o IIS Express na minha rede

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, localhost

Olá estou tentando executar o `IIS do Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Empty Web` site para funcionar na minha rede então alterei esse arquivo

> ...\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\meuProjeto\
>   .vs\config\applicationhost.config

```
<site name="meuProjeto(2)" id="4">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\Nataniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\meuProjeto" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61914:192.168.0.104" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

observe que coloquei o ip local da minha maquina

então eu excutei esse comando no cmd em modo administrador

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.0.104:61914/ user=todos
```

Ele me deu a mensagem que foi adicionado, entao executei esse

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=61914profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow
```

ele me deu a mensagem OK

mas quando tento executar ele me da a mensagem

> unable to connect to the configured development web server

Se eu digitar http://192.168.0.104:61914 no navegador antes de dar o erro ele ta funcionando, mas depois da o erro e não funciona mais

tentei fechar o vs e abrir de novo reiniciar o pc, mas quando faço isso ele cria outra Tag Site no applicationhost.config com o name `meuProjeto(X)` com o `bindingInformation` com `*:61914:localhost`

desse forma ele exibe essa mensagem

> unable to connect to the configured development web server 
>   Failed to register URL "http://localhost:61914" for site meuProjeto(2) application"/". Error Description Acesso Negado. (0x80070005)

Comment: Porque você não habilita o IIS da sua maquina e sobe lá sua aplicação.

Comment: Eu preciso que funcione de forma que eu consiga acessar pelo meu celular

Comment: Exato, use o IIS da sua maquina e não o ISS que o visual Studio levanta para roda sua aplicação.

Comment: Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Consegui configurar assim agora deu certo, valeu ai pela dica

Comment: Você pode configurar o [ISS](http://www.iis.net/) da sua maquina local para disponibilizar sua aplicação. Veja referencias para isso - http://blog.fabianobento.com.br/2010/07/como-instalar-configurar-iis/ - https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/f5af458e-40cb-4d5a-8c48-198c2d46e1fd/como-acessar-iis-75-em-outra-mquina-na-rede-windows-7?forum=winiispt - http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tins_manualWebIIS.html

Answer (score 2):

Como resolvi isso graças a dica do [GOKU SSJ4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/43340/goku-ssj4)

Primeiro foi preciso instalar o IIS para isso é so acessar painel de controle / Programas e recursos / Ativar ou Desativar os Recursos do Windows e marcar Serviços de Informações da Internet

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de terminar a instalação é só acessar o Gerenciador do Serviços de Informação da Internet (IIS), so procurar no iniciar, e adicionar um novo site

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então é so preencher estas informações, mas importante lembrar o caminho físico e selecionar seu endereço ip e lembrar a porta que você vai usar, e ja deixar marcado pra ele iniciar sozinho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então é so voltar para o seu projeto e publica-lo seguindo essas configurações

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembrando que você tem que publicar no caminho que você selecionou la na hora de criar o site do IIE
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso você não tenha liberado o firewall da porta é so abrir o cmd em modo administrador e mandar esse comando dai vc coloca o numero da sua porta no localport

> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in
>   protocol=tcp localport=80 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet
>   action=allow

Dai pra testar é so colocar o endereço ip e a porta e ser feliz
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa garoto. ...